# Insert a row on the Dataframe at the bottom and calculate the sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has many columns, I want to insert a new row to calculate the sum of the last 2 columns. I tried to use concat function but doesnt works. It add a new column not a new row. Is there has a solution?

Dataframe looks like this:

```
Date.      A.  B.  C.  D
2021-03-01 5.  10. 15. 20
2021-03-02 5.  10  5.  5
2021-03-03.5.  10. 10. 5
```

I tried to create a blank dataframe and concat the original DataFrame but the output was wrong.

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date'])
merge_df = pd.concat([returns,new_df])
```

I want the result like that:

```
Date.      A.  B.  C.  D
2021-03-01 5.  10. 15. 20
2021-03-02 5.  10  5.  5
2021-03-03.5.  10. 10. 5
sum_2      10  20. 15. 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding df:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
                     "A": [5, 10, 15, 20],
                    "B": [5, 10, 15, 5],
                    "C": [5, 10, 5, 5],
                    "D": [5, 10, 10, 5]})
```

Summing total:

```
df.loc["Row_Total"] = df.sum()
df
```

Summing only last 2 rows:

iloc - https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-get-the-last-n-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-in-python

https://www.kite.com/python/docs/pandas.DataFrame.iloc

```
df.loc["Row_Total"] = df.iloc[-2:].sum()
```

Comment: it is very usful. Thanks so much

Comment: Glad to help, at Your service :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas sum() function for this, by summing along the index.

Something like this.

```
df.loc['sum_2',:]= df.sum(axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this also -

```
result = df[df._get_numeric_data().columns.values].iloc[-2:,:].sum()
df.append(result, ignore_index=True)
```